# Plotting and calculating asymptotes in Excel with Apache POI in Java (or Visual Basic)

Tags: excel, vba, statistics

I am using Apache POI in Java to work with data in Excel (and also Visual Basic on the side, which I am less familiar with). I have the following problem which I would like to solve either by i) writing a method in Java or VBA ii) use a library function (if it exists) in either language iii) solve this problem directly in Excel.

**Problem description:** I have a chart in Excel (in fact a big number of them) which appears to plot data that has a horizontal asymptote. I think it's easiest if I illustrate this with a picture:

[image]

This data I used, which resembles the one I am working with, is

```
y - x
1   0.8232
2   0.6032
3   0.5012
4   0.4646
5   0.45001
6   0.44981
```

As you can see, there is an asymptote parallel to the x-axis, but the data comes from complicated real-life sources (as opposed to a mathematical formula) so it's not straightforward to calculate it. What is the best way to find the formula for the asymptote and/or draw it on the chart?

Although I have learned some statistics, I am not sure how to find asymptotes from data points, so I'd be happy with any help.